# How to check if post meta key exists or not in wordpress database

Tags: posts, post-meta

I want to check if post meta key exists or not, out side of the loop. Is there any WordPress function to check if post meta key exist or not in WordPress database. I have to check this outside the loop. Any help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Strategy to get post meta for use outside the loop](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/2128/strategy-to-get-post-meta-for-use-outside-the-loop)

Answer (score 36):

In case anyone else stumbles across this old question like I just did, it looks like the best way to handle this is using `metadata_exists()`

see https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/metadata_exists/

Here's what the syntax would be for post meta:

```
metadata_exists('post', $post_id, 'meta_key_to_check');
```

Comment: This is a good, clean answer - note that the first argument is not a post type, but an object group - basically linked to the parent table the meta data is stored in.

Answer (score 3):

You could use get_post_custom(POST ID GOES HERE) which will return a multidimensional array with all custom fields of a particular post or page.

So something like:

```
$meta_data = get_post_custom(785);
if ($meta_data['my_meta_key'][0] != "")
    ...
```

would allow you check if a particular meta_key was empty or not.

Comment: You should use `isset( $meta_data['my_meta_key'][0] )` to check if it exists. If you just want to know if it's empty OR not exists you can go with `get_post_meta` in the first place.